# Was it a Time Traveling Idol? Or just a Hallucination?

Tags: love-live

In the Love Live movie Honoka meets an [older woman](https://myanimelist.net/character/135102/Female_Singer) in NY, singing "What a wonderful world.

[image: Honoka and "Female Singer" in NY streets]

That woman then goes on to give live coaching to Honoka, and knows awfully lots about her,

> Including the fact she used to dare jumping mud pools as a kid as shown in the first scene of the movie.

No one of the other muses can see her, she is afraid of going near Homura's Japanese sweets, and seems to show up right where honoka needs her to be.

Also, her eye color is a dead-ringer for "older Honoka".

So, is she...

1. Time traveling honoka that comes back in time to fix everything.
2. A hallucination honoka is having. She is not real, and Honoka bought/found the mic stand somewhere.
3. HonoMaki DBZ fusion from another reality.

Word-of-God sources preferred, but feel free to base your own analysis on the movie material alone.

Who really was "Female Singer"??

Sources:

- https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1435102
- https://www.reddit.com/r/LoveLive/comments/3km7lg/love_live_the_school_idol_movie_discussion/

Comment: My bet is no. 2 or no 4. a stalker fans.